# How to set metadata in sys_file_metadata for file id in TYPO3 6.2

Tags: typo3, metadata, exif, typo3-6.2.x, fal

I try to update the medatadata informations (EXIF) for images in a folder. Via the StorageRepository I can read the metadata from file system. I now want to put the recieved information into the TYPO3 database. I think I found the corresponding mysql table called `sys_file_metadata` where the informations are stored for each file id.

My question now is, if there are any functions or methods to put the recieved metadata into the database or do I have to put it in via a mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the datahandler for this. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/UsingDataHandler/Index.html

And indeed it's stored in `sys_file_metadata`